# ZF2 ServiceManager - adding new module

Tags: zend-framework2, servicemanager

I started learning ZF2 but have a problem with ServiceManager.

I tried to add new Module "Menu" to ServiceManager.

In my application/config/module.config.php added this code:

```
'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
            'menu'       => 'Application\Menu\MenuServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),

    'menu' => array(

    ),
```

Application\src\Menu\MenuServiceFactory.php:

```
namespace Application\Menu;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

/**
 * Menu
 */
class MenuServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        // Configure the Menu
        $config = $serviceLocator->get('Config');
        $menuConfig = isset($config['menu']) ? $config['menu'] : array();
        $menu = Menu::factory($menuConfig);
        return $menu;
    }
}
```

Application\src\Menu\Menu.php:

```
namespace Application\Menu;


/**
 * Menu
 */
class Menu
{

    /**
     * Instantiate a menu
     *
     * @param  array $options
     * @return Menu
     */
    public static function factory($options)
    {

        $menu = 'test';
        return $menu;
    }


}
```

If I tried add this "$menu = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('menu');" I received:

```
    Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException

File:
E:\Projects\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:871
Message:
While attempting to create menu(alias: menu) an invalid factory was registered for this instance type.
Stack trace:
#0 E:\Projects\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php(494): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory('menu', 'menu')
#1 E:\Projects\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php(441): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
#2 E:\Projects\zf2\module\AdminSettings\src\AdminSettings\Controller\SettingsController.php(193): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('menu')
#3 E:\Projects\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(83): AdminSettings\Controller\SettingsController->logoAction()
#4 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#5 E:\Projects\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(472): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#6 E:\Projects\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#7 E:\Projects\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#8 E:\Projects\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#9 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#10 E:\Projects\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(472): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#11 E:\Projects\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#12 E:\Projects\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(294): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#13 E:\Projects\zf2\public\index.php(13): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#14 {main}
```

Does anyone have an idea to resolve this error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The path for your `MenuServiceFactory.php` file doesn't match the namespace you've defined in the service manager config.

You need to move your `Application/src/Menu` folder and all the files it contains to `Application/src/Application/Menu`

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank ypu.